# Taxonomy templates in a multilanguage site

Tags: taxonomy, multi-language

Let's say I have a multilanguage (English and Spanish) site with a custom post type called Books, with two custom taxonomies, Authors and Publishers.

The template files used to render the taxonomy archives in English would be:

taxonomy-author.php

taxonomy-publisher.php

My question is, do I have to duplicate this file for the Spanish version too, like this?

taxonomy-autor.php

taxonomy-editorial.php

Is there a way to avoid having to do this for every language in my site?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The templates use the *internal name* of the taxonomy. These will be the same in all languages.

The internal name is the first part in `register_taxonomy($taxonomy, $object_type, $args)`. What your users *see* is the translated name from the labels.

So, no, you don’t have to recreate the templates for each language.

Comment: when I translate a taxonomy (which seems to be necessary to use it in the other language) the in_category() function returns just based on the slug. Is there a different function I should be using? or is 'translating taxonomies' causing the issue